# monitor user click activity on ads (adsense or other network)

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I am thinking to track all user clicks on the ads I have on my website (including adsense and other network)

Do you think this would be possibile maybe adding an event listener with jquery that sends an ajax call before the user can open the advertiser page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have all ads wrapped in a container with class `ad` you could do:

```
$('body').delegate('.ad', 'click', function(){
  //YOUR AJAX CALL HERE
});
```

I'm not quite sure, if this works with flash content, but you could give it a try.

Comment: I was thinking to add an event listner for every link on my page, then for the link starting for example with http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/ I will do the ajax call...

Comment: Can be done in an equal manner `$('body').delegate('a', 'click', function(){ /*check link target */})`. But I think you will miss all links that are done from inside a flash content. Do not bind an event to each a-element, use delegate.

Comment: Additionally binding lots of events can make some browsers slow. Delegate just binds one event on the body and uses event bubbling to capture the event.

Comment: so which is the differences between delegate and live ? :D

Comment: with live jQuery has to search once for the specified selector, with delegate it does not. Otherwise $('body').delegate('a' ... and $('a').live(... are identically. Additionally you with delegate you can specify a different delegation target than the body element